# How to increase size of custom cursor image?

Tags: html, css, cursor

I want to increase a size of image which is used as cursor.

Currently i am not able to put image more than 128 by 128.

But i want to put it with more size.

so how to do that?

I am using

```
cursor: url(hand.png), auto;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine css + jQuery if necessary, even if combining them is not always perfect:

JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/n4Zbr/258/

Local example:

```js
$(function(){
  var $cursor = $('#huge-cursor');
  $(document).bind('mousemove',function(e){
    $cursor.css({
      left: e.clientX - 15,
      top:  e.clientY - 15,
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0; padding:0;
  cursor: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"), auto;
}
#huge-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10% 90% 50% 50% / 10% 50% 50% 90%;
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="huge-cursor"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>LONG<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>CONTENT
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>LONG<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>CONTENT
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>LONG<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>CONTENT
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>LONG<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>CONTENT
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>LONG<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>CONTENT
```

Comment: Your images are gone. It would be great to include your solution here rather than off-site.

Comment: Better use e.clientX combined with position: fixed.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS? I am afraid it can't be done. I think you should try to use some software which can edit icon file and re-size it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS (or JavaScript) to hide the 'real' cursor. Then create a div with the background and size of the new cursor which will reposition itself to where the 'real' hidden cursor is every time the mouse moves. Basically it will look like a real cursor but the disadvantages to this is that i don't think the hide cursor CSS property works in the browser Opera. If you are interested in this method, let me know I will post it up once I'm near a computer (not on an iPad)